# Understanding L2-norm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices, x and y, which are the same size. They are two estimations of the same data field. I want to quantify the difference between them across the whole matrix. Is `norm(x-y,2)` how this is normally done? What units is this in - if x and y are velocities in mm/sec, and I want to turn the L2-norm into a percentage of some reference velocity, does that make any sense?

Should this belong in Math?

Comment: You probably want to read up on matrix norms first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: Please clear what are the dimensions of your matrices. If the matrices only hold some quantities why did not you use an array? By the way norm metric does not change units.

Comment: Each matrix is 100x100 and represents the velocity across an x-y grid.

Answer (score 1):

Norm 2 of a matrix in Matlab is equal to root square of sum of squares of all elements. The all norm functions do not change units( its because you apply both square and root-square).

If you want compare the result with a reference velocity, it is better to use other measures like [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) (**Root Mean Square**). It is similar to norm but you should normalize the sum of squares before applying the root square. (this measure also does not change units)

The RMS of this matrix can be interpreted as :
How much velocity is changed at each place (x and y) in average.(the unit is mm/sec)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "quantify the difference", so this is what I do know...

> > norm(x) == norm(x, 2)

Equivalent since L2 norm is default. From matlab help

*n = norm(X) returns the 2-norm or maximum singular value of matrix X.*

So, if the max singular value of the difference of your two matrices is what you want, then you have the right function.

Answer (score 0):

`norm(X,2)` or just `norm(X)` will give you the l2 norm or the euclidian norm of X. X can be a matrix or a Vector. Be it a vector or a matrix, norm will be calculated by first squaring all elements, then summing them up and taking a square root yielding a single value as the answer. What you are trying to do will in some sense give you the magnitude of the difference between the two matrices. The units will be same as that of matrix elements.